# 2007 Suzuki Reno

Tags: obd-ii, suzuki, wiring-diagram

My OBD2 port has been damaged and I bought a replacement but I can't find the pin out for it. I have 8 wires that I need to know exactly where they belong into the connector. Please help. The wire colors I have are
2-black,
Orange,
Lt blue,
Dk blue with white stripe,
Lt green,
Green,
Purple.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Unless you get an answer here that gives a reliable source, you might want to go to the dealer or a professional manual to get a diagram. Many mudules are routed here and a mistake could be serious.